# What if anything can/should I do about `update failed for AnAction with ID=ToggleBreakpointEnabled` that I get every time I compile?

Tags: android, android-studio

Suddenly I'm getting this error:

`NullPointerException: update failed for AnAction with ID=ToggleBreakpointEnabled`

I have no breakpoints set, if this means anything:

[image]

When I click the link `nullPointerException` in the console, this pops up, so I submitted it as is an option (the link to `Issue 143...` does nothing):

[image]

Here's the Exception:

```
Update failed for AnAction with ID=ToggleBreakpointEnabled
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.debugger.engine.JVMNameUtil.getClassAt(JVMNameUtil.java:323)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.BreakpointWithHighlighter$4.compute(BreakpointWithHighlighter.java:462)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.BreakpointWithHighlighter$4.compute(BreakpointWithHighlighter.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:921)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.BreakpointWithHighlighter.getPsiClassAt(BreakpointWithHighlighter.java:458)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.FieldBreakpoint$1.compute(FieldBreakpoint.java:124)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.FieldBreakpoint$1.compute(FieldBreakpoint.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:921)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.FieldBreakpoint.getPsiField(FieldBreakpoint.java:121)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.FieldBreakpoint.isAt(FieldBreakpoint.java:307)
    at com.intellij.debugger.ui.breakpoints.BreakpointManager.findBreakpoint(BreakpointManager.java:397)
    at com.intellij.debugger.actions.ToggleBreakpointEnabledAction.findBreakpoint(ToggleBreakpointEnabledAction.java:52)
    at com.intellij.debugger.actions.ToggleBreakpointEnabledAction.update(ToggleBreakpointEnabledAction.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.doUpdate(Utils.java:187)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroup(Utils.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroup(Utils.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroup(Utils.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroup(Utils.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.fillMenu(Utils.java:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.fillMenu(ActionMenu.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.access$400(ActionMenu.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu$MenuListenerImpl.menuSelected(ActionMenu.java:235)
    at javax.swing.JMenu.fireMenuSelected(JMenu.java:1043)
    at javax.swing.JMenu$MenuChangeListener.stateChanged(JMenu.java:1122)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultButtonModel.java:349)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setSelected(DefaultButtonModel.java:232)
    at javax.swing.JMenu.setSelected(JMenu.java:311)
    at javax.swing.JMenu.menuSelectionChanged(JMenu.java:1190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.menuSelectionChanged(ActionMenu.java:209)
    at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.setSelectedPath(MenuSelectionManager.java:118)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicMenuUI.java:450)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6513)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**Is there anything I should do?** Nothing seems amiss about my apps.